# Dwarves paralysed by Roc

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm a newbish player, and right after starting a new embark I found that there was already a "resident" in my area. I tried to give my neighbour a wide berth, but he recently elected to perch, unmoving, on a cliff far above my plant collection area. Now I have a series of dwarves trying to pick up the same White Yam Plant[2] who, arriving within sight range of the bird, get terrified and apparently just stand there. One of them is dying of thirst. How do I get them to come back to my fortress? I can't fight a Roc.

[image: Ooo look a bird]

Comment: Edit: I did all the yam forbidding and movement restriction I could, but it hasn't snapped my dwarves out of their daze.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can try, the first one is to designate a burrows and restrict civilians to it. This is a great way of preventing them from being outside and in a certain region. You can, in fact, set an order for dwarves to be inside only using o-->i. However, their fear for self-preservation will usually override this by scaring them in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the one item, you may find it easiest to just Forbid the item. Dwarves ignore Forbidden items, and will not attempt to store them.

But if the trouble you're running into is plants beneath a Roc, you're probably not just in trouble with a single item! In that case, I suggest: <kbd>d</kbd>signate -><kbd>b</kbd>uilding/item properties -><kbd>f</kbd>orbid, and then draw the zone over the entire field of plants.

Not sure if this will unstick your paralyzed dwarves, but it should stop any further dwarves from being drawn into the Yam's siren spell.